# How to calculate the area of Circle and Square using classes? (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to use classes to calculate the area of a square or a circle (so, I have 5 files: `main.cpp`, `square.h`, `square.cpp`, `circle.h`, and `circle.cpp`) My program is running, but the calculations are just showing "0" for the area. I'm new to C++ (so even more new to classes). Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is what I have done thus far:

---

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Square.h"
#include "Circle.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

double radius = 0;
int length = 0;
Square square;
Circle circle;
int ch;

cout << "*** Press 1 or 2 on which shape's area you would like to calculate 
***\n\n1.) Area of circle\n2.) Area of square" << endl;
cout << "\nEnter your choice: " << endl;
cin >> ch;

switch(ch)
{
case 1:
{
    cout << "\nEnter radius of the circle: ";
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "\nThe Area of the circle is "<< circle.getArea();
    break;
}
case 2:
{
    cout << "\nPlease Enter the length of the Square's side: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "\The Area of the square is "<< square.getArea();
    break;
}

default: cout<<"\n Please enter a valid choice!";
break;
}

return 0;
}
```

---

### square.h

```
using namespace std;

class Square
{
private:
int length, area;

public:
Square(int length = 0);
int getLength()const;
void setLength(int length);
int getArea() const;
};
```

---

### square.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

Square::Square(int len)
{
length = len;
}
int Square::getLength()const
{
return length;
}
void Square::setLength(int len)
{
length = len;
}
int Square::getArea() const
{
return length * length;
}
```

---

### circle.h

```
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
private:
double radius, area;

public:
Circle(double radius = 0);

double getRadius()const;
void setRadius(double radius);
double getArea()const;

};
```

---

### circle.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"

using namespace std;

Circle::Circle(double r)
{
radius = r;
}
double Circle::getRadius()const 
{
return radius;
}
void Circle::setRadius (double r)
{
radius = r;
}
double Circle::getArea() const 
{
return radius * radius * 3.1415926;
}
```

Comment: You should take the time to read a tutorial about how to use your debugger so you can narrow this down to some specific part of the code which does not work the way you expect.

Comment: well... what is the area of a square with a length of 0?  to be a bit more specific... where are you setting the length and radius of your objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never actually setting the length of your square, nor are you setting the radius of your circle, when you are using:

```
cin >> length;
```

and..

```
cin >> radius;
```

You never call `square.setLength(length);` or `circle.setRadius(radius)`, with your defaulted parameter for both of these values being 0... well anything multiplied by 0 is 0.

If you use a debugger it will let you step through the code, so you can pay attention to the values of your variables, and catch errors like this much easier.  I would recommend looking up what debugger's are typically used with your compiler, and then learn to use it.

Comment: I know this says not to say "thanks", but you don't understand how long I've been working at this (again, very new to C++). Thank you so much Eddge!!